# binding my subquery where I obtain the amount to my main query

Tags: sql-server, data-binding, binding, subquery

I need help with binding my subquery where I obtain the amount to my main query. fundID is the field I need to bind to.

This is the statement I wrote to add the remaining balance (negative value) for each fund but the subquery returns more than one value. Is there a way I can bind the fundID in the subquery that retrieves the amount to the main query's fundID?

```
update [transaction]
set amount = amount - (select (a.amount + sum(b.amount)) amt
                       from [Transaction] a
                            inner join [transaction] b on a.FundID=b.FundID
                                                     and a.TransactionBatchID=b.TransactionBatchID
                            inner join fund c on a.fundid=c.FundID
                       where a.TransactionBatchID=19253 and a.TransactionTypeID=1308 and a.TransactionCategoryID=82
                        and b.TransactionCategoryID=83 and c.PoolID=78
                       group by a.amount, b.fundid
                       having a.amount * (-1) <> sum(b.amount))
where transactionid=(select max(transactionid)
                     from [transaction]
                     where TransactionBatchID=19253
                       and TransactionTypeID=1308
                       and TransactionCategoryID=83
                     group by fundid)
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: good use of whitespace is really important for writing any language too, I suggest starting to use it.